# Change route parameters without affecting subroutes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I have a route `/a` with some parameters (such as `/a;foo=1;bar=2/`) and two sub-routes: `/a/x` and `a/y`.

Component responsible for route `a` fiddles with parameters `foo` and `bar` and changes them depending on the user input. It also updates the parameters in the route, as shown above.

Can I **update route parameters without changing sub-routes** (or manually having to read them and re-apply them)?

This is how I navigate through code, if I know the sub-route (`x` or `y`):

```
this.router.navigate(['/a', params, 'x']);
// or
this.router.navigate(['/a', params, 'y']);
```

I hope for a method along the lines of the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['/a', params, /* don't change */])
```

If I completely leave out the last element of the array (`x`/`y`), it just always gets redirected to `x` since that's the default route.

Versions: **core 2.0.0-rc.5** and **router 3.0.0-rc.1**

Comment: Sounds similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8956, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7378 I think to remember that there was another issue that fits better to your requirment but I couldn't find it. I guess you have to traverse the router tree and rebuild a new route where the parameters that should change are replaced. I don't think there is something available out of the box.